# This simple program on JavaFX doesn't show up the popup menu. The event triggers (it prints out "22222222222"), but nothing shows up on right click

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

I was doing my big project, and when it came to a context menu, it didnt work out, i tried in a simple project to make sure the complexity of my project blocks showing up the popup menu, but even on a simple one it didnt work out, seems like a bug

```
package org.example.testinterface;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("Удалить"));
        contextMenu.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1500, 1000);
        canvas.setOnContextMenuRequested(contextMenuEvent -> {
            System.out.println("2222222222222222222222222222");
            contextMenu.show(canvas.getScene().getWindow(), contextMenuEvent.getX(), contextMenuEvent.getY());
        });
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1500, 1000);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: The context menu shows up for me, just not in the location you think. This is easily explained if you just read the documentation for [`ContextMenu.show(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html#show(javafx.scene.Node,double,double)) and [`ContextMenuEvent.getX()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/ContextMenuEvent.html#getX())

Comment: Replace `getX()` with `getScreenX()` and same for `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getScreenX() / getScreenY(`) instead of `getX() / getY()`.